# Ubuntu routing problem between two physical ports

Tags: iptables, network-interface, routing, nat

Looking to solve a problem on:

- Ubuntu 18.04.5
- Intel i3

I have two physical ports (enp1s0 & enp2s0), a router connected to enp1s0 and a camera on enp2s0.

- enp1s0 is 192.168.1.10
- Router connected is 192.168.1.1
- enp2s0 is 192.168.0.10
- Camera is 192.168.0.1

I would like to be able to access the internet from the camera.
(for example: ping -I enp2s0 1.1.1.1).

```
|———--|    |—--——|
enp1s0      enp2s0       
|_____|    |_____|
    |         |
    |         |
  |--———|      Camera
  Router
  |_____|
    |
    |
    Internet
```

I have tried the following rules:

- Enabling IP forwarding via:

  ```
    #vim /etc/sysctl.conf
    net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

    #sysctl -p
  ```
- Updating IP tables

  ```
    iptables -A FORWARD -i enp2s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp2s0 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp1s0 -J MASQUERADE
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -J MASQUERADE
  ```

I'm still not able to make the two interfaces talk - looking to ping enp1s0 from enp2s0, then access the internet from enp2s0. They have to be on different subnets.

Can anyone help me understand the routing problem here to help these two subnets talk to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally added this as an edit - but here it is as an answer:

I've used iptables flush to remove any old rules (although I believe this is done on restart anyways) and changed the nat rule from what I originally thought was correct.

```
iptables --flush
iptables --table nat --flush
iptables --delete-chain

iptables --table nat --delete-chain

iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface enp2s0 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do is to take the whole subnet `192.168.0.*/24` (which only happens to have the camera in it), and use NAT on your Ubuntu machine to pretend everything from this subnet actually comes from the Ubuntu machine. And you need to do this only because the router only accepts connection from the subnet `192.168.1.*/24` (if the router did not have this restriction, you could just do normal routing, without NAT).

This means you need a **single** rule for NAT, namely for the outgoing interface, which is `enp1s0`. NAT works through a connection tracker, so for outgoing packets, the source address will be replaced by the address on `enp1s0`, and for returning packets, the destination address will get replaced by the original source address.

So try with the single rule, then do something on the camera to try the connection (or replace the camera with a second computer, so you can do a `ping`). You **cannot** test this via `ping -I` on the Ubuntu machine, as this won't use the forwarding tables.

If the setup still doesn't work, do a `tcpdump` on both `enp1s0` and `enp2s0` while producing traffic from the camera; that should give you enough information to narrow down any additional problems.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 
I made the single NAT rule change and no luck.

I connected my macbook to the ubuntu machine (instead of the camera) and I am not able to traceroute to 1.1.1.1 or 192.168.1.10.
I did turn on tcpdump for enp1s0 and only saw things when pinging the interface from my macbook (which works), but trying to ping or traceroute to enp2s0, no traffic was present.

Comment: On the macbook, you need to set `192.168.0.10` as the default route to make anything excepct `192.168.0.*/24` go to enp2s0. You can make that automatic by setting up a DHCP server for `enp2s0` on your Ubuntu. Your camera may or may not need this (potentially is has a static address and static routes, but I'd need to know more about your camera to say).